# Are connections on a private network secure enough to not use HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https

I have (for example) 2 digital ocean droplets that can talk through their local network. I can use the local ip and not the public ip. If I need to pass sensitive info between those two servers can I use http instead of https since the request is not exiting the network?

Comment: No. [NSA infiltrates links to Yahoo, Google data centers worldwide, Snowden documents say](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/nsa-infiltrates-links-to-yahoo-google-data-centers-worldwide-snowden-documents-say/2013/10/30/e51d661e-4166-11e3-8b74-d89d714ca4dd_story.html)

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/513493/can-i-use-ssl-termination-for-sensitive-data-and-if-not-what-is-the-point-of-ev

Answer (score 2):

What is you'ur threat model? What are you protecting against? What, for that matter, are you protecting? We cannot make that business decision on your behalf, nor would you want us to do so.

You own the resources (transmission, processing, data, and the costs thereof), and so you must determine what risks you will accept.